# What is the etymology of "Mexi-ducken"

Tags: etymology

It is a compound invented by the TV show "The Colbert Report". You can find the context [here](http://www.dailykos.com/story/2011/09/29/1021189/-Stephen-Colberts-brilliant-mockery-of-the-GOP-anti-immigrant-base). (the Mexi- of course stand for mexican)

Comment: For those who are not familiar with it, *The Colbert Report* is a satirical program. The coinage, and the sentiments expressed along with it, should not be taken seriously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The context is:

> Especially when it comes to pregnant illegals.  They're the most devious kind, because they sneak across our border with another immigrant hiding inside them.  OK?  For all we know, there's another one hiding inside the baby!  **(A Mexi-ducken)**

This comes from **Turducken**, an American way of cooking turkey for Thanksgiving dinner: a chicken is placed inside a duck, and the duck inside the turkey. Hence, Turducken.

Comment: So charming, isn't it?

Comment: An American way of cooking? It's an American coinage for an ancient preparation, not particularly American.

Answer (score 0):

This is a play on [turducken](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Turducken), a dish created by stuffing a chicken into a duck into a turkey.  He is discussing a situation where an immigrant is pregnant (having an immigrant inside) and that baby also an even smaller one inside it.  So, similar to a turducken in that it is also 3 layers nested inside one another.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the chicken-in-duck-in-turkey [turducken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turducken)-influenced etymology, another direct influence is ***ducken*** as used in playstation game [Monster Rancher 2](http://monsterrancher.wikia.com/wiki/Ducken): "Also known as Dakkung, ... obtainable by ... winning a special doll ... The doll could then be combined with two other monsters to create a Ducken. ... They are wooden multi-colored ducks with a segmented section in their torso."  This is slightly reminiscent of [matryoshka or babushka dolls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll) that contain multiple layers of smaller dolls inside.